# Dell LATITUDE D630 won't power on. Need help diagnosing

Tags: hardware-failure, dell-latitude

So, I was using my laptop, which is indeed pretty old (Got it in '07). (As soon as I got it I replaced Windows Vista with XP.) Now, all of a sudden the computer powered off. The battery was almost dead when this happened. So, I plugged it in to charge it, and it has been charging for over 6 hours.

Atlas, I went to turn it on, and the power light turns on for a second, then goes off. Nothing ever happens.

I am assuming this is a battery problem, if so how would I go about replacing it? Also, if this could be something else I would be pleased to hear any suggestions. Thanks.

EDIT

See here: [http://www.amazon.com/Replacement-Li-ion-battery-Latitude-Laptops/dp/B0011X5I7U](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0011X5I7U)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that the computer is from 07, you could have lots of dust built up in the system. Dust can create extra heat in the system. The computer could have overheated to the point where it is broken. Heat can damage computer parts easily. However you could also have a bad charger that is providing less then normal power.

Do you have a second charger or a friend that might? Trying to blow the dust out of it might help if you can.

Comment: The dust inside the fan correct?

Comment: Dust can get into the fan and that can degrade the fan but also heat can also get on the fins of the heatsink causing the dissipation of the heat to reduce.

Comment: And no, I do not have a second charger.

Comment: So let me get this straight. You suggest I clean out the fan, look for damaged parts (If I can locate any). However it is quite possible that the battery died.

Comment: Yes or the charger could be dead. However based on the age of the laptop heat can also be a factor in causing the problem.

Comment: True. Since I was playing Minecraft and for this machine that is pretty graphic intensive.

Comment: Oh, but the light on the battery box is on, if that means anything.

Comment: If you where playing Minecraft then I think that heat could be the factor. If the battery light is on then it could be charging however if the battery is dead it might not be taking the charge.

Comment: Yeah, but what part would it have effected. The hard drive? The fan broke?

Comment: It could be the power system in the laptop

Comment: So how should I fix it. Simply getting a battery won't help will it. Or do you mean the heat damaged the battery, which seems unlikely.

Comment: I am thinking that the heat could have damaged the power system on the laptop. It might have to be sent for repairs at Dell or an authorized repair center but due to the age I am not sure if they would repair it.

Comment: I doubt they could. Warrenty isn't valid, it's really old, and I got this refurbished. But not from Dell I believe.

Comment: It might sound odd but I would also try this. Remove the battery and unplug the charger. Leave the laptop overnight and try it when you wake up. Sometimes that fixes problems with starting it.

Comment: Just a note on the battery... you don't need it in the unit to operate the unit.  I'm not speaking generically in this case... I'm speaking specifically of the Latitude D630.  Under optimal conditions, you can remove the battery, plug the adapter into the unit, turn it on and use it just fine.  Thus... if *your* issue were being caused by the battery, you could determine this by removing it, plugging it in, and powering it on.  If it runs fine, you are correct in your assumption that it is the battery.  Otherwise, if the problem persists, you should look elsewhere (as suggested).

Comment: Well, as icebox3d suggested, removing the battery, and leaving the computer overnight did solve the problem. However, I would still like to know why that happened. If anyone knows why, let me know. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Well, I think it allows all the capacitors to fully discharge.

Comment: @icebox3d. Okay, good to know. Thanks for your help. It is working for now. But I do not plan to play Minecraft on it anyway. (It's funny really. I almost never play games, but the one time I do, it almost breaks my laptop. Go figure.)

Comment: Yeah Minecraft is a heavy game both game and server side. I have a few E3s that cry when running MC servers :3

Answer (score 0):

Dells can be picky about chargers and possibly won't accept the charging if it's off-brand or 65w vs 90w.  Is it the original charger for that model?  Verify.

Comment: Yes it is the original charger. Thanks though, but it is working now.